# Joining SQL lookup table with data table

Tags: sql, join, database-design, lookup

I have a lookup table say cities with fields CityId, CityName

```
CityId   CityName
1        New York 
2        San Francisco
3        Chicago
```

I have an orders table which has fields: CityId, CustId, CompletedOrders, PendingOrders

```
CityId CustId CompletedOrders PendingOrders
1       123   100             50
2       123   75              20
```

I want a table/report that lists orders details of a given customer in all cities, i.e. the result I need is:

```
CityId CityName      CustId CompletedOrders PendingOrders
1      New York      123    100             50
2      San Francisco 123    75              20
3      Chicago       123    0               0
```

How to do that ?

Comment: what database, what version ??

Comment: In order to properly show code or tables, please highlight those lines and use the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar! Otherwise your post will be very unclear and chaotic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT
  c.CityId
  c.CityName
  o.CustId,
  o.CompletedOrders
  o.PendingOrders
FROM cities c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON ( c.CityId = o.CityId )
```

This will return all the rows that you want, but for the rows that don't exist in `details` it will return `NULL` values, so you would get:

```
CityId CityName      CustId CompletedOrders PendingOrders
1      New York      123    100             50
2      San Francisco 123    75              20
3      Chicago       123    NULL            NULL
```

The solution to get `0` instead depends on your database. With MySQL use `IFNULL`, with Oracle use `NVL`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select c.CityId,c.CityName,o.CustId,o.CompletedOrders,o.PendingOrders

from orders Left join cities 

on o.CityId = c.CityId
```