# How to display data in sqlserver 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using sql server 2008.i have one table which contains two columns.one is movie name and other one is rating.my table structure like that:

```
 MovieName | Rating
 ABC       | 3
 XYZ       | 2
 DEF       | 1
```

i used following statement to display my table records.

```
 Select * from tablename
```

what i want means instead of display the rating as numbers it should display, good for rating 3,better for rating 2 and worst for rating 1.

i.e)

i want like this

```
  MovieName | Rating
 ABC       | Good
 XYZ       | Better
 DEF       | Worst
```

can anyone tell me how to display like this using sql statement??

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT MovieName,
    CASE WHEN Rating = 1 THEN 'Worst'
    CASE WHEN Rating = 2 THEN 'Better'
    CASE WHEN Rating = 3 THEN 'Good' END AS Rating
FROM tablename
```

The better solution would be to have one more table with the ratings and join the 2 tables to display the result:

```
SELECT a.MovieName, b.Description AS Rating
FROM movies a JOIN ratings b on a.Rating = b.Rating
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to map on the fly:

```
SELECT MovieName, 
 CASE Rating
    WHEN 3 then 'Good'
    WHEN 2 then 'Better'
    WHEN 1 then 'Worst'
  END AS Rating
FROM TableName
```

Preferably however, you should make use of a [Lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015207/joining-sql-lookup-table-with-data-table) and then the `Rating` column of `TableName` can be foreign keyed and then joined to this table to retrieve the Rating. This will have the benefit of enforcing referential integrity, and will also allow the rating names to be changed (or made e.g. cross language friendly) without hard coding into the code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in case you have just these 3 ratings, a fast and simple solution would be:

```
SELECT MovieName, 
CASE rating 
    WHEN 3 then 'Good' 
    WHEN 2 then 'Better' 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Worst'
from table
```

But if you intend to create more ratings I recommend creating another table (lookup table) which holds the rating names.

```
Ratings

Rating    RatingName
1         Worst
2         Better
3         Good
4         Supercool
```

When you have this set up, you could do this operation much easier.

```
SELECT m.MovieName, r.RatingName
FROM movies m join ratings r on m.rating = r.rating
```

This will allow you to insert more rating "types" and you won't have to change the query (my first query) and add case situations for the aditional ratings. After adding more rating types and movies with other ratings, they will appear automatically in your results.